# How to check if localStorage is empty or not in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

So I'm trying to check if localStorage is empty or not and if it's then I want my state to be changed immediately.

I've created this state and I'm setting this state initially empty

```
const [isLoggedIn, setLogin] = useState();
```

Then I'm using useEffect hook to get item from localStorage if something has in localStorage it will set my state true otherwise false

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("info") !== null) {
    setLogin(true);
  } else {
    setLogin(false);
  }
}, []);
```

So, when I add something or delete from my localStorage it doesn't work and I need refresh my page in order to make it work.

I've created a code sandbox to check what's going on, please have a look and help to make it work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-mclaren-vypyo?file=/src/App.js:164-304

Comment: LocalStorage isn't reactive, it doesn't alert when it's updated. Also, use a lazy state initializer function to red from localStorage and set the initial state value so it's available on the initial render cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Your localStorage commands look correct. But the issue is that you are not checking the storage everytime. You should have a state variable which you can use to indicate that something has changed and the storage needs to be checked again.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setLogin] = useState();
  const [change, setChange] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("info") !== null) {
      setLogin(true);
    } else {
      setLogin(false);
    }
  }, [change]);

  console.log(isLoggedIn);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <h1>LocalStorage has something</h1>
      ) : (
        <h2>LocalStorage has nothing</h2>
      )}

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          localStorage.setItem("info", "true");
          setChange((change) => !change);
        }}
      >
        Add to Local
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          localStorage.removeItem("info");
          setChange((change) => !change);
        }}
      >
        Remove to Local
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the above code, `change` is changed when one of your storage command runs. You could have had a counter or anything else too. The main purpose is to check the storage everytime you are chaning stuff. This way you can have multiple storage commands (even more than 2), and then you can check your storage after every change.

[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-rgb-krfv1?file=/src/App.js:0-940)

Another simple approach could be to simply set the logged in state inside your functions where you run `localStorage` commands :

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setLogin] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("info") !== null) {
    setLogin(true);
    } else {
      setLogin(false);
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn]);

  console.log(isLoggedIn);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <h1>LocalStorage has something</h1>
      ) : (
        <h2>LocalStorage has nothing</h2>
      )}

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          localStorage.setItem("info", "true");
          setLogin(true);
        }}
      >
        Add to Local
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          localStorage.removeItem("info");
          setLogin(false);
        }}
      >
        Remove to Local
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now you have one lesser state variable, but you will be directly manipulating the logged in state from your buttons.

[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-feather-qg35p?file=/src/App.js:0-844)

Comment: This is great! it's working absolutely perfect. I just want to add one more thing into it that what if I don't have a button to add data into localStorage and data coming directly from database instead clicking on button then how would I change the state to true or false when database add something into localStorage.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal check my answer, that uses a hook which  can be used in multiple places.and can handle complex data structures, i think it can handle the usecase you have here

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal if database is changing the data and you want to let your client know, you will have to use sockets. the client will listen using sockets and the backend code(which is manipulating the DB) will send an event. Based on that you will update your state. This is a much more complex use case and you should first try something and ask a seperate question when you have an issue

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal also please mark this answer as accepted to complete the question

Answer (score 0):

If you don't setItem("info") I mean If "info" does not exist in localStorage then you'll get "null" and your code will work. But If you set something to "info" in localStorage for example if you do localStorage.setItem(""), then you won't get null, you'll get empty string. Therefore your code should be:

```
useEffect(() => {
if (localStorage.getItem("info") !== null || localStorage.getItem("info") !== "") {
  setLogin(true);
} else {
  setLogin(false);
}
}, []);
```

if you use array instead of string in "info" then

```
useEffect(() => {
if (localStorage.getItem("info") !== null || JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("info")).length > 0) {
  setLogin(true);
} else {
  setLogin(false);
}
}, []);
```

Comment: Can you please post an working example ?,

Comment: I've already edited your code. You can put my code in your example. It will work. 
Have you set localStorage.setItem("info",value) in somewhere in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on the load of the page, you are setting the existence/non-existence of the localStorage item in the state of the component. However, when an action (`setItem`/`removeItem`) is performed, you are not updating the state. The simple way to accomplish it is to update the state in the event listener itself.

```html
<button onClick={() => {
    localStorage.setItem("info", "true");
    setLogin(true);
}}>Add to Local</button>

<button onClick={() => {
    localStorage.removeItem("info");
    setLogin(false);
}}>Remove to Local</button>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-hill-k8h6j?file=/src/App.js:0-856) is an updated, forked sandbox link.

Comment: This is nice! what if I don't want my state dependent on buttons, mean data directly coming from database?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Please be clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **qs**.

Then localStorage.setItem("info", qs.stringify(your_value_you_want_to_store));

```js
if (!qs.parse(localStorage.getItem("info"))) {
    setLogin(false);
} else {
   setLogin(true);
}
```

Comment: What does this `!qs` does?

Answer (score 0):

I added an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-hamilton-dku69?file=/src/App.js).

What is going on is that, the localstorage isnt reactive, and therefore you cannot listen to changes on it directl. you will need a mechanism to listen to changes. therefore i created a custom hook, that can get and set local storage values, and i used that instead.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function getStorageValue(key, defaultValue) {
  // getting stored value
  const saved = localStorage.getItem(key);
  const initial = JSON.parse(saved);
  return initial || defaultValue;
}

export const useLocalStorage = (key, defaultValue) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    return getStorageValue(key, defaultValue);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // storing input name
    console.log("called", value);
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue];
};
```

Now if you set new changes, you will get an updated state. Fell free to extend it however you like.

Comment: I don't know why when I tried this code and my localStorage has something it says true but when nothing in there it says undefined instead of false

Comment: i set the value to null, i realised that is what you were doing, but you can set any value you want. You can also extend it to delete @ShivamAggarwal. Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage isn't reactive, it doesn't signal back to react components when it's updated.

You should initialize your state from localStorage, and persist state update to localStorage. The button click handlers should only update the local `isLoggedIn` state.

1. Use a lazy state initializer function to read from localStorage and return the initial state value.
2. Use an `useEffect` hook to persist the state to localStorage.
3. `button` `onClick` handlers update local state.

Code:

```
function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setLogin] = useState(() =>
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("info"))
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("info", JSON.stringify(isLoggedIn));
  }, [isLoggedIn]);

  console.log(isLoggedIn);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoggedIn ? (
        <h1>LocalStorage has something</h1>
      ) : (
        <h2>LocalStorage has nothing</h2>
      )}

      <button onClick={() => setLogin(true)}>Add to Local</button>
      <button onClick={() => setLogin(false)}>Remove to Local</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-to-check-if-localstorage-is-empty-or-not-in-react-js]